# Is AngularJS $scope always bad and impact performance so hard?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, npm, bower

I'm doing application in angularjs. But at work my team leader whant as to use pure javascript and or jqlite as much as we can. He whant as to avoid $scope, and make all DOM manipulation by traditional way as getElementsByClassName and change it with .html() function.
Is this approach good? Is $scope that bad and impact performance?
And also he wanted as to delete bower and use only npm. His argument was, not to use two managers...? Is he right?

Comment: One of the biggest reasons to use angular is the two way data binding.  if you have angular in your project and you don't use it's data binding capabilities, it's really doing you no good at all.

Answer (score 2):

1) In Angular 1, it's not using `$scope` that you should avoid, but **it's adding too much watchers**. If you're using Angular 1, you should take advantage of the data-binding it offers.

Though, if you find yourself with a directive loading a table containing 50K lines, you might want to do some optimizations ...

2) About getting rid of bower: I agree with him (npm already does what bower does, why have two different package managers ?)

Comment: ad. 1 I agree with you.
ad. 2 I didn't notice that npm v3 is available ;)

Comment: As far as  $scope is concerned, try to use one-way binding as much as possible- in this way you will reduce the number of watchers. Manipulating DOM with jqlite or vanilla js in Angular apps doesn't sound very... 'angular way'.